# Using XMPP for Request Response

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, openfire

I would like to know if **is it possible to get XMPP messages sent by mobile client applications in my PHP Back end server**?

The PHP Back end server will process the messages (JSON request) and send responses back to the client mobile apps. There will be 5 million client application users sending messages to server simultaneously.

Comment: It is generally possible to connect a PHP backend server to an XMPP server (check for PHP libraries [here](https://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html)). However it's not clear to me if you are looking for a PHP server implementation of XMPP or if you want to connect via PHP to an [XMPP server](https://xmpp.org/software/servers.html)

Comment: I have a server developed in PHP which has all user info and content management. At present mobile applications are communicating directly to PHP service with location for getting content (HTTP Get request). This consumes high battery. Is it possible to put an XMPP server (Openfire) for handling this scenario? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use XMPP but definitely for that, you will need alot of changes.

Your mobile clients will send data in XMPP packets (message or iq) and you will have to handle those stanzas and parse them to get the data (which can be JSON).

So, Yes you can use XMPP but you need to have such skills (both on client side and on server side).